# I work 8 hours per day at the office. Is it possible to have a dog if I live in a studio?

Tags: dogs

My question is: is it possible to leave your dog alone in your studio for 8 hours? Is there any breed that will be ok with that? How do people that have regular jobs have dogs?

Comment: I really don't know, but I'm against it, it's not fair for a dog to stay alone for so long, even more unfair if you have a puppy. Try to set up a dog sitter that would look out for the canine while you're out.

Answer (score 7):

An adult dog, yes. A puppy, no.

As a general rule, you can expect a puppy to be able to "hold it" for about one hour per month (i.e. a 3-month old puppy can go for 3 hours without going outside). Of course, just because it's possible for the dog to hold it, doesn't mean they are potty-trained which will take time.

You also want to consider what the dog will be doing while you're away. Will he be crate trained and stay in the crate? Will he have free reign of the studio? Either way you want to make sure the dog is getting enough physical and mental exercise while you are home so he doesn't become destructive.

As for breed restrictions, if you're gone for a long time regularly, you should look for a lower-energy dog. Shelters and rescues are a great place to find older dogs that may already be mostly potty-trained. Also consider hiring a dog-walker to come by and play with the dog.

Lots of people with jobs have dogs and the dogs are happy so it's very possible. Our dog is alone for about 7–8 hours 4 days a week and she's perfectly happy, but we do a lot of training and exercise with her when we are home.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I am not working at the moment, so I would go with a puppy. But plan to have a 9-5 job in the near future. Do you recommend any breed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any breed recommendations at this time, but there are couple of survey sites out there where you can put in the characteristics you're looking for and get some ideas.

Comment: I think Shelters and rescues are the best option, as you can then get a older dog, that has shown its self to be happy on its own all day.

Comment: Most shelters will be wary of rehoming to someone who's out this long.

Comment: A tired dog is a happy dog. Dogs can  be left alone considerably longer if you get them good and tired first. I would suggest that 8 hours alone isn't great though, and you should probably consider a lunchtime visit (or a dog walker coming by) because whilst _some_ dogs are ok for this long, not all are.

Answer (score -1):

That's ridiculous and not only absurd to insinuate that a person working an AVERAGE work week of 40-50 hours a week cannot own a dog. If this was the case then our shelters would be even more overrun with dogs. Not to mention overwhelmed with euthanizing them. The average nine-to-five (whether working or just absent) person can own a happy dog and be content with their abilities. Even when I'm home my dogs sleep and rest most of the day so what gives if I'm home or not.  They simply need stimulation, exercise and enrichment like every living being does. Dogs were bred to be companion animals but we aren't all Queen Elizabeths to have a dog on our lap 24/7. And dogs have adapted to their human counterparts lifestyles.

You simply need to ensure to give them 30 minutes to 1 hour of walks/runs outside time per day (depending on dog size and breed). Not just leave them in the backyard because bonding does not occur that way either. On top of that you provide playtime - 10-15 minutes of tug of war, fetch or having fun with their toys is good enough. Finally enrichment. This means giving your dog a change of pace once in a while. This can be a car ride to a new change of scenery, socializing at a dog park or hiding treats around the house for them to find can also provide enrichment as well as brush up training or teaching new tricks for 5 minutes at a time daily. Enrichment is giving your dog a change of pace.  Think of new scenery, new sounds, new smells, new trainings, new activities to stimulate them mentally.

Look, that totals about 1 hour a day. If you can do that I promise you both you and your dog will be content. Don't talk about 8 hour workdays being unfair to the dog (that's not true), because this is what almost all dog owners have to deal with - earning an income - and your pet will adapt as well. Every dog deserves a loving home and you can provide that love outside of your schedule.  Just like your own exercise is important enough to make time for, you give priority to your dog just the same and believe me, you will reap more reward than the cost of owning a pet dog.

Studies show dogs help us live longer and they make great bed mates. People are happier when they have a dog sleeping in their bed. Just incorporate your best friend in your life and you will both be more than happy and filled with gratitude. Don't think about rules of etiquette or what so called experts recommend, take it from me. I am a long time dog owner, trained groomer, pet companion specialist and trainer and you can own and love a dog while working a 40-50 hour long week. Yes, if you have additional support like spouse's, mom's, kids' or others' that can increase their enrichment by all means - take advantage. It's healthy for both them and your dog anyways and resources are always a blessing.

But long story short. You can and will benefit a dog's life working a normal job work week and they will undoubtedly benefit yours. Many dogs need homes so please rescue dogs before buying from breeders and know you are making a big difference and you'll reap every reward. Like the saying goes - WHO SAVED WHO?  Only adopters understand what that truly means. Join the club.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE. This honestly reads like a rant not taking into consideration different activity and space requirements for different breeds, but it looks like there's some useful information in there. If you edit it down to just the relevant parts, this would be a good answer.

Comment: No one is insinuating that it's not ok to work and own a dog. Your attitude is a little adversarial. Can you please edit your post to be less combative?